# Full date varchar to date

Tags: mysql, sql

I need convert a varchar field, to date.

My varchar look like this:

```
 Jan 11 17:18:53 +0000 2011
```

I need:

```
2011-01-11
```

Any ideas?

I tried with:

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(my_field, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d') mydate
```

but this returns NULL.

EDIT - MORE DETAILS:

Query (string data_field):

```
 SELECT date_field FROM my_table LIMIT 1;
+--------------------------------+
| date_field                     |
+--------------------------------+
| Tue Jan 11 17:18:53 +0000 2011 |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date_field, '%Y') FROM my_table LIMIT 1;
+---------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE(date_field, '%Y-%m-%d')   |
+---------------------------------------+
| NULL                                  |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

// Other query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(my_field, '%b %d %H:%i:%s +0000 %Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') FROM my_tableLIMIT 1;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------+
| DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(my_field, '%b %d %H:%i:%s +0000 %Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------+
| NULL                                                                           
|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

------- EDIT FINAL -------

**SOLUTION!! YEYYY!!**

In the response of @paul, he's recommend me try this:

```
DATE(STR_TO_DATE(my_field, '%b %d %H:%i:%s +0000 %Y'))
```

And this works correctly!

Message for all proyects managers and developers:

NEVER save dates in varchars fields PLEASE!!!!

Thanks for everyone!

Comment: What does the +0000 do and what if it is +0010 (for example)

Comment: I don't know but if is necessary, cut this part of the string. I need the date in format YYYY-mm-dd

Comment: `Jan` is `01` not `06`. You either mean `Jun` or the result should be `2011-01-11`.

Comment: I tried STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(my_field, '+0000', ''),'%Y-%m-%d') but return NULL

Comment: I corrected the date @PaulSpiegel my bad..

Comment: Let this be a lesson to NEVER store a date field as varchar.

Comment: @Eric I'm a outsourced developer on this proyect, this is a HORRIBLE practice, i know! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `+0000` part is always the same and doesn't matter, you can use:

```
DATE(STR_TO_DATE(my_field, '%b %d %H:%i:%s +0000 %Y'))
```

The used specifiers here are:

```
Specifier | Description
----------|------------
       %b | Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec)
       %d | Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
       %H | Hour (00..23)
       %i | Minutes, numeric (00..59)
       %s | Seconds (00..59)
       %Y | Year, numeric, four digits
```

See the full list of specifiers in the documentation under [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: i tried this but returns NULL

SELECT DATE(STR_TO_DATE(my_field, '%b %d %H:%i:%s +0000 %Y'))

Comment: @AlexisCervetto How coud I know about `%a`? There was nothing about the weekday in the original version of your question.

Comment: I dont know why yesterday %a worked for me. Rigth now i run my SQL query and its true.. %b is correct, i read the documentation of DATE_FORMAT() and is the correct attribute... so crazy!

Comment: Omg... i found the problem X_X . I have two differents "dates" formats, like "Tue Jan 11 17:18:53 +0000 2011" and "2011-10-03T18:08:21.000Z"

Comment: "I have two differents "dates" formats" - Congratulations ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('Jan 11 17:18:53 +0000 2011 ', '%b %d %H:%i:%s +0000 %Y'), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer to help others understand it better. Code only answers are considered impolite and it may not help the OP understand the problem that you are trying to help with.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that +0000 is a fixed number.
so i would use

```
Select STR_TO_DATE('Jan 11 17:18:53 +0000 2011','%b %e %H:%i:%s +%f %Y')
```

Comment: `%f  -> Microseconds (000000..999999)` i have more a feeling that `+0000` indicates timezones

Comment: %f works also with 4 digit numbers. But timezone is a good idea

Answer (score -1):

You can use following query to get the required result:

```
select TO_DATE('Jan 11 17:18:53 +0000 2011', 'Mon DD HH24:MI:SS +0000 YYYY')
```

For more formatters you refer to following link:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-formatting.html

Comment: The question is tagged with mysql.